# Consumer producer with dropping off

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a thread (producer) that acquires data from some source every `t mSec`. Once the data is acquired and ready, other threads (consumers) should get the data and do some processing on it.

However, There is no guarantees which thread is faster (the producer may be slower or faster than the consumers.

What I did:

```
//Producer
while(is_enabled_) {
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex_);
    ready_ = false;
    //acquiring the data
    ready_ = true;
    lk.unlock();
    cv_.notify_all();
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(sleep_milliseconds < duration ? 0 : sleep_milliseconds - duration));
}
```

Considering the consumers all do the same:

```
//A consumer
while(is_enabled_){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex_);
    cv_.wait(lk, [this] {return this->ready_; });
    //Process the data
}
```

I do not have queues. Only the last acquired data should be processed and only once by each consumer. If some data was acquired and no consumer found time to process it, the data is dropped off and another data overwrites it by the producer.

On the other hand, if the consumers were faster than the producer, they should wait until a new data is ready instead of processing the old one.

The problem I am facing that the consumers are using the same old data produced by the producer if the producer was not quick enough to produce new data.

What does my implementation lack?

Comment: Have a global `shared_pointer` pointing to the most recent data packet. Producer would prepare a new packet and `atomic_store` it into the global. Consumer would `atomic_load` it (or `atomic_exchange` with null pointer, if only one consumer should get it).

Comment: What, if any, is the relationship between `mutex_` and `point_cloud_mutex_`, and between `cv_` and `point_cloud_cv_`? Why is consumer waiting for `point_cloud_ready_` to become true, when no one is setting it?

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry my bad, it is a typo

Comment: @JakeFreeman No error message but undesirable behavior as I mentioned

Comment: @HumamHelfawi have you tried using a switch variable. i.e. the data goes to the consumers which then turn a variable to false until there is new data?

Comment: @JakeFreeman I though of this but I was wondering of there is directly built in way.

Comment: You leave `ready_ == true` even after the data is consumed. So the next `wait` call will be satisfied right away, and see the same data.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I thought that wait will not try to check ready_ until a new notification come... thank you very much

Comment: You probably want at as many copies of the data as you have threads (readers + writers) and maybe a few extra so that you won't drop data too often.

Answer (score 0):

You could due something like this to achieve your goals:

Global variable: `std::vector<bool> newData;`

For the producers:

```
while(is_enabled_) {
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex_);
    ready_ = false;
    //acquiring the data
    ready_ = true;
   std::fill(newData.begin(), newData.end(), true);
    lk.unlock();
    cv_.notify_all();
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(sleep_milliseconds < duration ? 0 : sleep_milliseconds - duration));
}
```

In the consumers before the while loop do:

```
int index;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex_);
index = newData.size();
newData.push_back(false);
lk.unlock();
```

Then the body is like this

```
while(is_enabled_){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex_);
    if(newData[index]) {
        cv_.wait(lk, [this] {return this->ready_; });
        newData[index] = false;
    //Process the data
    }else  {
          lk.unlock();
          std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This contains a data race. Consumer accesses contents of `newData` outside the lock, even while producer modifies these contents.

Comment: Now, after processing the data, consumer thread enters a busy wait loop, monopolizing the mutex.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I added a sleep to the consumer threads so it does not hog the mutex

Comment: It sleeps while holding the lock, making matters worse still.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you are right I believe I have fixed it

Comment: Why not simply `cv_.wait(lk, [this] { return newData[index]; });` (and drop all the other checks and the sleep)? You simply have an array of ready flags instead of just one; other than that, your approach is no different than the OPs.